# Github with Git flow

Tags: git, git-flow

we've a normal Git flow with:

- Develop (and from here we start feature branches)
- Staging (we merge develop -> staging when we're ready)
- Master (our product env)

In each step we've a different build with different variables for test and simulate that our code and APIs are stable. 
That's what I had:

1. I "copied" (created other branches from develop) `develop` for generate `staging` and `master`
2. I started to create a new feature branch from develop and merge it on staging (PR from develop to staging) and then master (PR from staging to master). Everything was ok.
3. I had the same with another feature branch but when I tried to open a PR from `develop` to `staging` Github show an alert with **`This branch is out-of-date with the base branch`**. And I need to click the `Update branch` Button

We've the same problem with all other project and I'm sure that noone enter with a strange history on develop with a feature branch and also that noone pushed something directly on staging/master (are protected). What is happening?

We're using the default **merge** commit

Comment: I think what's missing from your workflow is merge master back into staging, and stating back into develop. When you accept a PR, I assume a merge commit is created, in which case that merge commit has to be brought into the staging and develop branches.

Comment: yeah that's I never had it before... but why that is happening? because that merge commit create a new commit on staging and develop don't have it?

Comment: So the recommended way to merge a PR is to create a merge commit, which lets you document in the commit log which PR was merged in. At this point, staging and develop are indeed out of date, because they don't have that merge commit. Merging back to staging and develop should be a fast-forward merge, which I assume is what the "Update branch" button does for you.

Comment: There's something that I can do for avoid this type of "merge back"? Because can be extremely hard to had it every time that I'll merge on staging

Comment: Well, you can use a fast-forward merge on your PRs if you prefer. The advantage is that you won't have to merge back. The downside is that it does not document the merging of that feature into staging or master. You have to assess the relative importance of that documentation trace in the log (although GitHub will keep an archive of your PRs, so the info is not lost, it's just not in the git log itself) vs simplifying your flow.